# Absolute Positioning with JQuery UI Position Method

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is there a way to make Jquery UI's position method use absolute instead of relative positioning in css?  To be clear, I am still looking to position one element relative to another on the page.  I just want the CSS mechanism by which that happens to be position:absolute instead of position:relative.  The reason is because the element that I am positioning is still taking up space on the page where it originally fell in the document flow.

Comment: Assuming you are using an external CSS file, just overwrite it.. otherwise, if you have access to the CSS file, can't you just modify it?

Comment: @JoshC Yes, that is what I ended up trying by chance and it worked.  What made you jump to that solution though?  I didn't see any reference to this feature in the documentation (could have been reading right over it).  To my understanding, JQuery must have detection of whether the element starts out in static or absolute positioning before it takes its positioning action, since the calculations are different (positioning relatively versus absolutely).

Answer (score 3):

My solution: I set the position for the element being positioned to `position: absolute` in my css file, and JQuery UI apparently automatically detected that, because it now uses `position:absolute` instead of `position:relative`, while achieving everything I was looking for.  If this solution doesn't work for you or is not the proper solution to the question, please let me know.

Also, if someone could please comment on why this feature is not in the documentation (or if it is and I missed it), I would greatly appreciate it.